# Is this "All Surface" Interior Detailer Spray really good for leather seats?

Tags: cleaning, buick, interior, lacrosse, leather

I have some "Turtle Wax All Surface Interior Detailer Spray". (I could only find it at [Wal Mart](https://www.walmart.com/ip/Turtle-Wax-All-Surface-Interior-Detailer-Spray-23-oz/487148988)) It says you can use it on vinyl, leather, and several other surfaces. The seats and dash in my 2014 Buick LaCrosse appear to be all leather and I want to make sure I'm taking good care of them. But the deodorizing properties of this detailer spray are a huge bonus for this car.

Will this spray be safe/good for the leather or is it safer to go with a dedicated leather/vinyl cleaner and have to miss out on the deodorizer? (I still plan to follow up a leather conditioner for the UV protection.)

Comment: What leather care products have you found? Soap? Leather cleaner? Leather oil? Personally I would not use a generic all surface cleaner…

Comment: Agree with Mike ... use something specific for leather.

Comment: The leather specific products I found are Meguiars Gold Class. "Leather and vinyl cleaner" and "leather conditioner".

Comment: Have you checked with the horsey people - they care for and treat leather... Many leather goods are still used for many purposes...

Comment: My Buick Lesabre has leather seats. From Walmart, I have been using ArmorAll Leather Care Gel monthly. The leather looks like new, not bad for a 1997 Buick. The product also rejuvenates the pebble finish vinyl top surface of the dashboard. For a deodorizer, use Febreze spray on your floor mats and other carpet areas.